# Python: 'import node.py' raises "No module named py"-error

Tags: python, python-import

I have a file main.py like this:

```
import node.py
[my code...]
```

and a node.py like this:

```
[more of my code]
```

When executing main.py, I get this error:

```
  File "/home/loldrup/repo/trunk/src/src/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import node.py
ImportError: No module named py
```

Comment: What tutorial are you using?  Where did you see code like this?  Can you quote or link to an example of this?

Answer (score 9):

You should just say `import node`. The `.` in the name makes python think you want to load a submodule named `py` of the package`node`, hence the error. All of this is explained in detail in the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Comment: Nope, then I get
    nodes.append(node(k,positions[k],posChanendsD[k]))

Comment: Ups, I ment: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Comment: Well you should not have a function that has the same name as a module. If you have a `node`-class in the `node`-module, qualify the name like this: `node.node(k,positions[k],posChanendsD[k])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function named `node` in a module called `node`, the clearest thing to do is:

```
from node import node
```

This adds the name `node` to the local symbol table and makes it reference the function named `node` in the `node` module.

It's often less confusing if you give the module and its members different names - though as you learn when you start working with the `datetime` class in the `datetime` module, it's not so confusing that the included batteries don't do it.

Answer (score -2):

I friend helped me out. It turns out I shall use:

```
from node import *
```

Comment: -1: Read this: http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#at-module-level.  It's a bad solution.